# Why isn’t the standard library calling a container remove function if it exists?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, erase, std

In *The C++ Standard Library*, it is said

> A container might have member functions that provide much better performance.

As SFINAE allows detecting whether such member function exists ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence), for instance), it shouldn’t be too complicated to write `std::erase` such that it calls a container's member function if it exists. Why doesn’t it do that?

Comment: Most containers have their own `erase()`, like `vector`.

Comment: And what should the `erase` function do if it does not exist?

Comment: @PlasmaHH well, nothing I guess

Comment: @qdii: Sounds pretty counterintuitive to me to call a function named erase that then does nothign...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard algorithms work with iterator ranges, not containers. Given an iterator, there's no standard way even to tell whether it comes from a container; and certainly no way to access the container if it does.

In order to support this then, as well as bloating the iterator requirements to support the metaprogramming you suggest, you'll also need to bloat each iterator with a pointer/reference to its container. That would be quite a high cost (since many iterator types are usually implemented as a single pointer), for an optimisation that would rarely be needed (since you usually know which type of container you're dealing with).

Comment: It's not just high cost, it's often impossible.  And for the given example, there's a problem with the semantics: `std::remove` has signficantly different semantics that `std::set<>::erase`, for example (and `std::set<>::erase` takes different arguments than `std::vector<>::erase`).

Comment: @JamesKanze: Indeed, changing `remove` to act like `erase` would be weird. A better use case might be `std::sort` vs. `std::list::sort`.